# How can we manipulate elements value in browser forms?

Tags: html, forms, hidden

How can we manipulate elements value in browser forms.

I have a signup form and i want to manipulate the hidden post data while submitting the form...please help me.

Comment: Be more specific on which event do you need to change your hidden data. You can give identification to your hidden input and then call a javascript function which can manipulate with your input, e.g.
onsubmit='document.getElementById("YourHiddenId").value="MyValue";'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the plugin 'firebug' in your browser . In this plugin you can get source code by which you can manipulate the elements of your sign in form and also you can add elements view hidden elements such as authenticity token and other hidden values and also you can change the data of your form fields. For more details hit this url:

http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: You don't need firebug for this task. Every browser has a builtin inspector that you can use without depending on 3rd party extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Press `F12` on your browser so you can change the form data.

You don't need any other dependencies such as `Firebug`. Every major browser has a builtin web inspector.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manipulate them WITHIN the browser, then open your browser's [Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/), as @Aristona suggested:

If you're using Google Chrome you can click the right button of the mouse over an  input and then "Inspect Element".

If you're using Firefox you can add the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) plugin, that let's you inspect the DOM.

With IE use the [Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359).  
Opera has a similar toolbar, but you get the idea.